# dpkg error, unable to install anything "resource temporarily unavailable", `dpkg --configure -a` hangs

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Every time I try to

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open 
   (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/),
   is another process using it?
```

Upon running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up linux-image-4.13.0-46-generic (4.13.0-46.51) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-46-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic) -- 
doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-46-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-46-generic
    /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-46-generic
    /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic
```

After this the upgrading stalls.

I am unable to install anything, there's always `dpkg` to be fixed. I have tried everything, but still nothing works.

Comment: Killed these processes, One was sudo dpkg --configure -a

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill processes using `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file with `fuser` utility with `-k` option:

```
sudo fuser -uck /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Monitor will be blinking during the `fuser` command execution
If `fuser` doesn't help remove `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Finally do:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I have applied as you said but still while installing it shows
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: @Debadatta Execute: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`